# What is hard bop?

Tags: genre, jazz, bebop

How can one define the jazz style *hard bop*? In which way is it different from bebop? Which are the main characteristics of the style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A Return to a more energetic way of playing. Playing "hot", but with more control than in the Bebop which is more accessible to a wider audience.
2. Bebop's purely harmonic and technical characteristics vanish and make room for a more melodic, smooth style of playing.
3. The themes are less complicated and more melodic.
4. A clear influence of Afro-American "roots": gospel and blues.
5. The drummer's playing is very present, rhythm and polyrhythm gain importance as a result of the African influences.
6. The use of suspend chords and pedal notes: gospel influence.
7. The line up is usually a rhythm section and two or three horns.

Comparison: bebop, cool jaz, hard bop.

[image: Comparison]

According to [this article](http://www.jazzinamerica.org/LessonPlan/8/6/211), there were two factions of hard bop:

> 1: Funky jazz was relatively simple (simple melodies, simple chord progressions, simple forms); its essence was one of groove and feeling and was heavily influenced by blues and gospel music.
>
> 2: Mainstream jazz was far more complex (more difficult melodies, improvisations, chord progressions, and forms); it was still about groove and feeling but added the complexities of bebop; a bit of arranging was often included as well (worked out introductions, endings, harmonized heads, background lines, etc.).

Examples:

[Horace Silver’s “Nica’s Dream”](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrxzKYdwsA) (mainstream)

[John Coltrane’s “Giant Steps”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4JywYmu2-s) (mainstream)

[Art Blakey’s “Moanin’”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cv9NSR-2DwM) (funky jazz)

[Miles Davis’ “Walkin'”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMW3RloxEyA) (funky jazz)

Comment: ... Bebop which is more accessible to a wider audience. How can you proof your statement?

Comment: Mainly black musicians?  Really?  That's not even comparative across the three tabled genres.